# Add role to new user not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I updated the Identity 2.0 code to add my own user properties for first and last name and then add a user to default role "user".

```
var account = new AccountController();
account.UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "user");
```

However, it does not work and says account is null.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong please?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email
        };

        //Add our custom properties
        user.Fname = model.Fname;
        user.Lname = model.Lname;

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var account = new AccountController();
            account.UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "user");

            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
       ....
```

Comment: Why do you initiate the *AccountController*? Just use the *UserManager* as you have done before when creating the user.

Comment: Do you mean use user.Roles.Add(theRole) or UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "cell") ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Horizon_Net - this works:

```
UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "user")
```